# How to get root context in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get JSON data in `Handlebars.registerHelper`

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderValue', function(name) {
   console.log(data); // How to get JSON data here?
});
```

I want to compare `name` with all the fields present in JSON bit don't know how to get hold of JSON in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for `this`

following works:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderValue', function(name) {
   console.log(this); // Gives me JSON 
});
```